# Can I change the temp folder path?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net app that uses `System.IO.Path.GetTempFileName()` for temporary files.  In the production IIS environment (W2K3), the temp folder (`System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()`) points to `C:\Windows\Temp`.  But on my XP dev machine it's `C:\documents and settings\machinename\ASPNET\temp`.

Is it possible to change this folder without affecting other accounts on my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I speak for the XP.

You can change the temp on your asp.net account only and affect only the asp.net.

**The easy dirty way**, open **regedit**, locate on **HKEY_USERS** the asp.net acount, buy navigate the tree, and look on **environment**, for the TEMP, TMP that have the aspnet/temp, and just change them, and reboot. Attention with regedit.

The other way is to log as aspnet, and change them from controlpanel | system | advanced | enviroment variables.

That way you change the temp directory affecting only the aspnet acount.

Comment: Thanks, option 1 did the trick perfectly.  For future reference I used SysInternals psgetsid.exe (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897417.aspx) to get the sid for the ASPNET user, since all the registry keys are sids.

Comment: Also, I like the "I speak for the XP." Reminds me of the Lorax. :-)

Comment: I know for good sysinternals, didn't know the psgetsid, thank you for that tip - I also never hear the lorax :) I search and find it now...